# Why doesn't Bumblebee work with Nvidia GT640M?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I've done a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 from a liveCD on a Samsung Series 7 Chronos with a 3rd Gen i7 and the Nvidia GeForce GT 640M.

I've followed this: (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) to install bumblebee so I can switch to my discrete GPU. I have not used ironhide, or preivous bumblee since it's a clean install.

When I use optirun, optirun says it can't initialize the GPU:

```
[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please

[ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

I've looked at the troubleshooting page for bumblebee and I have the correct driver and do not think I have aspci disabled.

Also, my keyboard becomes very unresponsive and my mouse skips and isn't smooth after optirun crashes. The only thing to fix this is a reboot.

Here's my lspci | grep VGA output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fd2 (rev ff)
```

It seems Ubuntu can see my graphics card. I don't really know what's going on.

Comment: I have the same laptop, nice machine, have you solved your problem in the mean time? What kind of driver do you use now?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Bumblebee Troubleshooting](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting) webpage

> Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0. Please ...
>
> PCI:1:0:0 may vary, but take a look at the last lines of the kernel
>   log (usually located at /var/log/kern.log, /var/log/kernel or
>   /var/log/messages). You're probably using an outdated driver or messed
>   a bit with improper ACPI calls (see above).

If you've already been over that, then you will need to file a [bug report with the bumblebee project](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Reporting-Issues), so that they can help diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already reported in the Bumblebee issue list #172:

GT650M: Failed to initialize NVIDIA GPU

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/172

I have the same issuse with my Dell Inspiron 17R-SE (Ivy bridge i7, GT 650M).
I tried different nvidia drivers (259.59, 302.17, 304.22, with the same failure.